# changing array dimension and type

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, dimensions

I'm newbie in matlab.
I have an array `50x100 uint8`, I want to change it to `5000x1 double`. how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `reshape(matrix_to_resize, new_row_size, new_col_size)` to resize the array. You should be able to use the resultant matrix and the `im2double(matrix)` function to convert the elements to doubles.

[The documentation for reshape.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html)

Comment: this error occurred: `Undefined function 'resize' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: Sorry, I meant reshape! Edited.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a single column of your data, the colon operator `:` is also an option:

```
 data = uint8(randi(10,50,100));
 result = double(data(:));
```

Comment: @diophantine In the question there is nothing about using `reshape`! OP only asks a way to convert a `50x100` matrix to a `5000x1` matrix, which is solved by my answer!